# Is there a way to iterate over objects in an array?

Tags: javascript

Say i have an array of objects:

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to iterate over the keys and values in the objects

I tried using a for loop

```
function checker (name){
  name = "";
  for(i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){     
    if(name === (contacts[i].firstName)){
      return "yes" ;
    }
    else{
      return "No such Contact";   
    }
  }
}

checker("Harry");
```

Calling the function with the argument "Harry" should be true and return "yes" , instead it's returning "No such contact"!

Comment: Maybe `name = ""` has something to do with it :)

Comment: you assigned empty string to name, and you're for loop will only run once because you returned, therefore it will only check the first element in array

Comment: Also you can do a one-liner : `const checker = name => contacts.find(c => c.firstName===name)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Nicholas Tower pointed, you're interrupting the loop execution with the return.

As you have there an array of objects, try instead

```
contacts.find(contact => contact.name === nameYoureLookingFor)
```

Array.prototype.find() will get you the first element that matches the condition. In this case, the object must contain a property name with a given value.
An object is a truthy value, so you could use a one-liner here

```
function checker(name){
    return contacts.find(contact => contact.name === name) ? 'yes':'No such Contact';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   name = "";
```

you're reassigning name to `""` instead of using the function's input value.

you're basically comparing

```
"" === contacts[i].firstName
```

which will always use the `else` statement based on your input data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var checker = (name) => {
  contacts.forEach(item => {
    if(item.firstName === name){
      return console.log('Yes');
    }else{
      return 'No Match found'
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways of doing it. As @Nicholas Tower said, in your exemple just moving the else return outside the loop would solve it:

```
function checker(name) {

  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if(name === (contacts[i].firstName)){ return "yes" ; }
  }

  return "No such Contact";
}

checker("Harry");
```

You could achieve the same in a cleaner manner with a for..of loop:

```js
function checker(name) {

  for (let contact of contacts) {
    if (name === contact.firstName) { return "yes" ; }
  }

  return "No such Contact";
}

checker("Harry");
```

...or a find:

```js
function checker (name){
  // will return the object if it exists, undefined if not
  const contact = contacts.find((contact) => contact.firstName === name);

  // convert to a boolean and return the 'yes' if truthy (the object), 'No such Contact' if falsy (the undefined)
  return !!contact ? 'yes' : 'No such Contact';
}

checker("Harry");
```